# Flash, using buttons (with mouse) to move

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So let me be clear here, I am not trying to drag something, which is all that I can find on keeping something activated whilst something is clicked. I would like to know how to move something while it is clicked, I have made a version where you use the mouse but I am making it in to an app, do I need to use anything other than the mouse functions?

Code:

```
mright.alpha = 0;
mleft.alpha = 0;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
function move(e:Event)
{   
    if(player.y >= 33 && player.y <= 763)
    {
        mright.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mrgh);
        function mrgh(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            player.y -= 1;
        }

        mleft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mlft);

        function mlft(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            player.y += 1;
        }
    }
    else if(player.y < 33)
    {
        player.y = 33;
    }
    else if(player.y >= 763)
    {
        player.y = 763;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very bad code where you add the same eventlistener on each frame. You should instead set a boolean and deal with it inside the mouse event listener.

Comment: where did i add the same event listener?

Comment: it does move but only every time i click

Comment: what's your problem man ?!

Comment: I want it to constantly move while the mouse is held but cant figure that out, it only moves when i click

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**AS3 code :**

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10)
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timer_on_Timer)
function timer_on_Timer(e:TimerEvent){
    move_player()
}
timer.start()

var btn_left_pressed = false
var btn_right_pressed = false

btn_left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, btn_left_on_Press)
btn_left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, btn_left_on_Release)
function btn_left_on_Press(e:MouseEvent){
    btn_left_pressed = true
    btn_right_pressed = false
}
function btn_left_on_Release(e:MouseEvent){
    btn_left_pressed = false
}

btn_right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, btn_right_on_Press)
btn_right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, btn_right_on_Release)
function btn_right_on_Press(e:MouseEvent){
    btn_right_pressed = true
    btn_left_pressed = false
}
function btn_right_on_Release(e:MouseEvent){
    btn_right_pressed = false
}

function move_player(){

    if(player.y >= 33 && player.y <= 763){
        if(btn_right_pressed){
            player.y -= 1
        } else if(btn_left_pressed){
            player.y += 1
        }
    } else if(player.y < 33) {
        player.y = 33
    } else if(player.y >= 763) {
        player.y = 763
    }

}
```

This is of course a very easy code that works, but you can add many things like **start** and **stop** **timer**, ...

Comment: Happy to hear that, if it is that you want you can set your question as answered.

Comment: Use ENTER_FRAME for apps.

Comment: one thing though, when you play for a bit, it will start to speed up. Have you got any ideas why?

Comment: I saw nothing of such, but verify if the code is not executed many times.

Comment: what do you mean? I have put a trace in to the move part and it does repeatedly execute while the mouse is held

Comment: put a trace before ` timer.start() ` and tell me if it's executed once or many times.